# Creating a swift helper class to handle CoreLocation functions

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager

I am new to Swift and I have managed to create a starter app which gets the current GPS location. Now I am trying to create a helper class (Location.swift) which will perform all the GPS location-based functions and can be called from my main ViewController (e.g. Location.getGPSLocation() where getGPSLocation is a static func in my Location.swift helper class).

Please review my code for the Location.swift helper class:

```
    import Foundation
    import CoreLocation

    public class Location
    {
    private static let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    public static func getGPSLocation()
    {
        let authorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

        if (authorizationStatus == .notDetermined)
        {
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            return
        } else if (authorizationStatus == .denied || authorizationStatus == .restricted)
        {
            print("ERROR: Please enable location services")
            return
        } else
        {
            startLocationManager()
        }

    }

    private static func startLocationManager()
    {
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()
        {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }
}
```

I now get an error message for the above code "Cannot assign value of type 'Location.Type' to type 'CLLocationManagerDelegate?".

How can i get around this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your `Location` object needs to inherit `NSObject` and `CLLocationManagerDelegate`. Second you need to provide a `shared` instance property and change your manager declaration from static to an instance property. Third override your `Location`  initializer, call super and then enable your locations services and set your manager delegate there:

```
import CoreLocation
class Location: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    private let manager = CLLocationManager()

    static let shared = Location()

    var location: CLLocation?

    private override init() {
        super.init()
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            manager.delegate = self
            manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            manager.distanceFilter = 10
        }
    }

    static func requestGPS() {
        Location.shared.manager.requestLocation()
    }
}
```

Now you can implement the delegate methods extending Location:

```
extension Location {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        self.location = locations.last
        print("location", location ?? "")
    }
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,
                                  didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        print(#function, "status", status)
        // check the authorization status changes here
    }
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,
                                  didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(#function)
        if (error as? CLError)?.code == .denied {
            manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            manager.stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback regarding the singleton class.